# Changing mysql root password on Windows after removing mysqld-nt.exe

Tags: mysql, windows

I am trying to  change password of MySQL root by following the steps here:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/resetting-permissions.html

unfortunately the **mysqld-nt.exe** doesn't exist in Windows anymore according to thread here http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?11,206806,207257#msg-207257

So how would I go about this which exe is the replacement now. I should mention I have MySQL server 5.6

Thank You,

Saher

Comment: Not a programming question. Ask on [dba.se]

Answer (score 0):

I got that work using otherwise a much simpler way:

sign in normally to mysql on command line or using the MySQL workbench;

```
mysql -u root -p
```

Use mysql database

```
use mysql;
```

update user password using simple update query.

```
update user set password=PASSWORD("NEWPASSWORD") where User='root' and Host = 'localhost';
```

then flush:

```
flush privileges;
```

Done!